# how to set REG_KEY_DONT_VIRTUALIZE flag in c#

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry, uac

My question is very simple, but i dint found an answer googling long time.
How to set `REG_KEY_DONT_VIRTUALIZE` flag to registry key created by me (i.e. `HKLM\Software\MyApp`)?
I want my program to be user-independent. Every user starting my app should have access to the same configuration options located in that location).
Changing application manifest I can disable registry virtualization by running program as administrator, but I want normal user be able to run the program and read registry values.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your app to be virtualized then you use a manifest to indicate that. If you use `REG_KEY_DONT_VIRTUALIZE` on your key then all that will happen is that all the writes will fail because your users won't have write access to HKLM.

If you want all your users to share configuration then you'll have to store the configuration in a file rather than the registry. There's nowhere appropriate in the registry that is shared by all users and allows standard users write access.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty unclear, virtualization is only enabled for legacy non-UAC compatible programs and reading is always permitted.  I have to assume that *writing* is the problem.  Change the permissions on the key with, say, your installer or Regedit.exe so that Everybody has write access.

Comment: Are you really advocating putting an ACL on a registry key in HKLM to all everyone write access to that key? Doesn't sound like good practice to me.

Comment: @David - allowing all users to modify a shared resource isn't a good practice, whatever it looks like.  That ship already sailed.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing or adding ACLs to the key, you can ensure that the key you are using programmatically is viewing the 64-bit part of the registry by using the `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey` API with the `RegistryView.Registry64` flag.

This appears to work properly for 32-bit applications regardless of whether or not registry virtualization is enabled for the app.

```
private const string MyRegistryKeyPath = "Software\\My Company\\My App";

private static RegistryKey OpenMyAppRegistryKey(bool requireWriteAccess = false)
{
    using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
    {
        return requireWriteAccess
            ? baseKey.CreateSubKey(MyRegistryKeyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
            : baseKey.OpenSubKey(MyRegistryKeyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
    }
}
```

If `requireWriteAccess` is false, this method will return `null` if the specified key does not exist.

I should also point out that this code will require elevated permissions to open the key for write access.  But I believe it ensures that unelevated reads using keys opened in this fashion will only come from the 64-bit view of the registry.

Answer (score 0):

To date, there is no C# or C API to set the registry key flags.

I assume the safest way is to launch the REG.exe command line tool using CreateProcess.

But, for the record, I have pasted some 'C' code from [this blog](http://mygreenpaste.blogspot.co.uk/2008_04_01_archive.html) which demonstrates another way using an undocumented API:

```
typedef enum _CONTROL_FLAGS {
    RegKeyClearFlags = 0,
    RegKeyDontVirtualize = 2,
    RegKeyDontSilentFail = 4,
    RegKeyRecurseFlag = 8
} CONTROL_FLAGS;

typedef struct _KEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFORMATION {
    ULONG   ControlFlags;
} KEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFORMATION, *PKEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFORMATION;

typedef enum _KEY_SET_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    KeyWriteTimeInformation,
    KeyWow64FlagsInformation,
    KeyControlFlagsInformation,
    KeySetVirtualizationInformation,
    KeySetDebugInformation,
    MaxKeySetInfoClass  // MaxKeySetInfoClass should always be the last enum

} KEY_SET_INFORMATION_CLASS;

NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI NtSetInformationKey(
IN HANDLE               KeyHandle,
IN KEY_SET_INFORMATION_CLASS InformationClass,
IN PVOID                KeyInformationData,
IN ULONG                DataLength );

typedef NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS (NTAPI* FuncNtSetInformationKey) (
    HANDLE KeyHandle,
    KEY_SET_INFORMATION_CLASS InformationClass,
    PVOID KeyInformationData,
    ULONG DataLength ); 

BOOL CRegLonMigration::SetDontVirtualizeFlag(LPCTSTR keyPath)
{
    FuncNtSetInformationKey ntsik = (FuncNtSetInformationKey)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle( _T("ntdll.dll") ), "NtSetInformationKey" ); 
    KEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFORMATION kcfi = {0}; 

    kcfi.ControlFlags = RegKeyDontVirtualize | RegKeyRecurseFlag; 
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    LSTATUS status;
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == (status = ::RegOpenKeyEx(ROOT_KEY, keyPath, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey)))
    {
        NTSTATUS status = ntsik( hKey, KeyControlFlagsInformation, &kcfi, sizeof( KEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFORMATION ) ); 
        RegCloseKey( hKey ); 
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```